# How to best present a long list of icons in a responsive layout?

Tags: mobile, info-visualisation, responsive-design

On desktop, we have a list of logos on a page. However, when we design the mobile responsive, each logos just stack on top of each other. It becomes a very looong list. What is the best way to present these list of logos on mobile?

DESKTOP:

[image]

MOBILE:

[image]

Comment: You buttons seem to be centre bed. Set align to none and display to inline for mobile devices. Only works where icons are same size though.

Comment: If having them spaced out seems like a waste of space, then maybe additionally scale them down to a reasonable size? Mobile users are generally accustomed to having smaller UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

I must be missing something. What's wrong with allowing your icons to fill all the space they need and having one column on very small screens, 2 columns as soon as the space allows, then 3, etc, etc??

Just set your list of logo elements to `display: inline-block` then go to the pub, they'll align themselves from that point to fit whatever container they find themselves in.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest visually grouping your icons in case there is a context of which they can be grouped by; if you have icons for weather then you could group them together on a row or in a box-type container. This obviously depends on what sort of icons we are talking about and how small/big the mobile device / icons are. Like [these groupings, with or without a descriptive tag.](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

If the icons simply are 'just big enough' for a desktop, but way too big for a mobile device, then you might have to make the icons smaller when a user is using a smaller device, either by detecting the viewport or the actual size of the device.